# Getting individual lists from an R by object

Tags: r

If you have data like:

```
x<-1:100
c1<-cut(x,breaks=10 )
result<-by(x,c1,function(x){
                     list(n=length(x),
                          centralTendency=c(mean=mean(x),
                          median=median(x)) ) } )
```

Is it possible to get a vector of n, and a list of vectors with the central tendency?  This is a very simplified form of my problem, which is actually n data points and 280 icc values, so please don't try to calculate the mean and median more efficiently.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: 1) for this case a vector n=c(10,10,10,10,10,10...) 2) a list ( '(0.901,10.9]' = c(5.5, 5.5), '(10.9,20.8]'=c(15.5,15.5) ... (90.1,100]=c(95.5,95.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
n <- unname(sapply(result, function(x) x$n))
#or as per @Frank 's comment
sapply(result,`[[`,"n") 

#n
#[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

And for central tendency

```
ct <- lapply(result, function(x) x$centralTendancy)
#or as per @Frank 's comment
lapply(result,`[[`,"centralTendency")

#> ct
#$`(0.901,10.9]`
#  mean median 
#   5.5    5.5 
#
#$`(10.9,20.8]`
#  mean median 
#  15.5   15.5 
#
#$`(20.8,30.7]`
#  mean median 
#  25.5   25.5
```

Comment: I already have the calculation performed.  I just want to get the values not recalculate the mean/median

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you @Frank and lyzander

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1.  When you use the [[ function, you have to use backticks.  A small but very important distinction.

Comment: Actually it is @Frank that would deserve the second +1, since he mentioned the `[[` function :). But thanks for your kind words, it makes my efforts and time spent here worthwhile. Thanks :)